# migrating a linux driver to Android

Tags: android, makefile, kernel, device-driver

I'm porting a 3G modem written for Linux for laptops to an embedded android (Gingerbread) device with an ARM processor. I already got the device driver compiled (C code) as a module (.ko file) and installed. I see it when I boot the kernel and it runs well. It hooks up to the USB port as intended. It's happy ready to be talked to.

The next required piece is the "connection manager" written in C++. This is where I have a problem. This doesn't run in Kernel space but it is not a regular Android application with a user interface. This is a "task" running in background that should be started from the "init.rc" file at boot time. The makefile provided with the source code is good to set the dependencies but it is useless as far as the platform I want to target. I'm using the toolchain provided with the Android source code "arm-eabi-*" (runs off of a Ubuntu machine) that I used to compile Android and the kernel. I got lots of compile errors primary because it uses the standard "libc" libraries which doesn't exist in Android. I replaced it by the "bionic libc" which is a light weight subset version of linux libc for android. On top of it, it looks for "crt0.o" which is the start-up code a statically linked program in a linux environment(and several other OS). In Android it is dynamically linked at run time, therefor uses something else than crt0.o.

There is tons of information on Android app programming on the web but, very little on that kind of low level stuff.  If anybody has a working makefile for building that kind of C++ code to run as a background task under Android ARM, I would very appreciate to have a look at it or if there is any information that could help me find a way to do that.  Or if anyone has done something like that could give me some clues on how to achieve this.

Comment: Google has a tool to integrate some C++ code into an APP (NDK). It is a bridge between the Java and C++ code. The docs I can find is pretty much around apps and user interface. I'm not sure it applies to what I want to do because it generate some libraries used by the java code. In the Android folder "external/", I found some interesting C++ source code managing different things from several manufacturers. It seems to be built by a different built system based on "android.mk" files. I will put my code there and take it as an example and see what I get from it. Anybody knows more about that?

Comment: There is more docs found in "build/core" It starts with build-system.html and ANDROID-MK.html. IT is not complete and not up to date but this is a starting point

Comment: The HTML docs is outdated. But if you start with the "Makefile" in the project main folder, it leads you to the chain of makefile used for the Android build system which is totally different from Linux build system. In those makefile, there is a lot of comment describing what does what. I found that what I want to do is not done through NDK but would be part of android itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a year later, but here is a makefile that will compile a simple native app:

```
NDK_USR_PATH := $(NDK_USR)

C_FILES := $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard *.cpp)
O_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(C_FILES))
O_FILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(C_FILES))

out: $(O_FILES)
        @arm-eabi-gcc -o $@ $< -Bdynamic -Wl,--gc-section -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -Wl,-rpath-link=$(NDK_USR_PATH)/lib -nostdlib $(NDK_USR_PATH)/lib/crtend_android.o $(NDK_USR_PATH)/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -L$(NDK_USR_PATH)/lib -lc

%.o: %.c 
        @arm-eabi-gcc -o $@ $< -c -I$(NDK_USR_PATH)/include -fno-short-enums

clean:
        @rm -f *.o
        @rm -f out
```

It compiles any .c files in the same directory into an app named "out". It requires the environment variable NDK_USR to point to the ndk directory "ndk/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/".

This should dynamically link to the bionic libc, and should enable android driver development.

Be careful when copying and pasting the above makefile. Make is very specific about tab characters.

Comment: Thanks Andres. I will use that trick to compile C for android. In my Cell modem case, My real problem was that the low level interface layer (RIL) and the upper layer of the OS is different in Android and Linux. So, Porting was much worse than recompiling the code.